# Как называется значение при котором клавиша не нажата в языке Processing?

Tags: анимация, клавиатура, processing

Пишу значит игру на языке Processing, и надо включить анимацию бездействия если игрок ничего не нажимает, подскажите пожалуйста, я перерыл весь материал по processing, так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 0):

`!` -- означает логическое НЕ

`keyPressed` -- значит клавиша нажата

```
If (!keyPressed) {}
```